# An activity that will run after but regardless of another one's success?

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

Suppose I have activity X, can I define activity Y to be dependant on X (running only after X has finished) but regardless of whether X has succeeded of failed?

My concrete use-case for this is the following:  I have an activity that imports data from `S3` to `DynamoDB`. Before that I have a `ShellCommandActivity` that increases `DynamoDB`'s throughput and after it another one that decreases it back to normal. If my import activity fails for some reason, nothing decreases the throughput back.

Any other solution will be appreciated!